# while loop construction for use with `apply`

Tags: r, while-loop

I have a data.frame `df` like this:

```
df <- data.frame (x=1:5,y=1:5)
```

I want  to use an `apply` function row-wise to this data frame, where I check a condition that is dependent on both the `x` and `y` and then change the `x` and `y` elements until they meet my condition. In this example if `x` and `y` don't add up to 8 I keep picking new random numbers for them and try again.

I figured an `apply` function using a `while` loop would be best. So I tried the following:

```
checkchange <- function(x) while(x[1] + x[2] < 8) 
              { 
              x[1] <- sample(5,1)
              x[2] <- sample(5,1)
              return(cbind(x[1],x[2]))
      }
```

I would then plan on doing this:

```
newdf <- apply(df,1,checkchange)
```

This doesn't work. Should I be using `repeat` and a `break` or do I need to specify a `return` value more clearly. `while` loop grammar help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the curly braces for your anonymous function

This works for me:

```
checkchange <- function(x) 
              { 
              while((x[1] + x[2]) < 8)
                {
                x[1] <- sample(5,1)
                x[2] <- sample(5,1)
                }
              return(cbind(x[1],x[2]))
              }
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Nico pointed out, the function will work with additional braces.

```
checkchange <- function(x) {      
  while (sum(x) < 8) { 
    # no need to sample from 1:5 if the sum has to be at least 8 
    x <- sample(3:5, 2, TRUE)        
  }
  return(x)
}
```

The output of the `apply` needs to transposed to match the original arrangement of the data.

```
t(apply(df, 1, checkchange))
```

---

By the way, you don't need a loop for the function:

```
checkchange <- function(x) {
 if (sum(x) < 8) {
    x[1] <- sample(3:5, 1)
    x[2] <- ifelse(x[1] == 3, 5, sample(seq(8 - x[1], 5), 1))
  }
  return(x)
}
```

Comment: +1 Thanks sven great help, and preempted me on the `t`. Useful to think of shortcuts with the `ifelse` too!